# calucate number of times a string appears in a array and compare with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am stuck in getting no of times a string appears in array.
This is my array

```
let arr = [ "5281-A", "5280-A", "5280-B", "5281-B" ]
```

used the split("-")[0] to get only the alpabets

now i would like a end result as this(getting Alphabets from every Element)

```
newObj = [['A',2], ['B',2]]
```

now this doesn't need to be array it can be object.But i want this in this form cause then i would like to compare the newObj with the following array

```
resArray = [["A",2], ["B",1]]
```

and then return in this case that B has one less quantity.

Basically it is a will used for validation of two different tabs values before submission.

I am stuck with this for hours.
Help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: So alphabet will always appear at the last ?

Comment: Yes, i used split("-")[0], like this

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to get your array, then `Array.prototype.sort()` to get the array with the most repititions.

```js
let arr = ["5281-A", "5280-A", "5280-B", "5281-B"];
let arr2 = ["5281-A", "5280-B", "5281-B"];

// get the count of repititions
const getCountArray = (arr) => 
 Object.entries(
  arr.map((id) => id.split("-")[1]) // map the elements as "A" or "B"
   .reduce((a, c) => ((a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1), a), {})
 );

// return what is missing from two arrays
const whatIsMissing = (baseArray, secondArray) => {
  const [a, b] = [baseArray, secondArray].map(([[, a], [, b]]) => [a, b])
   .reduce(([a, b], [c, d]) => [a - c, b - d])
  
  return `A requires ${a} more, and B requires ${b} more`;
}

console.log(whatIsMissing(getCountArray(arr), getCountArray(arr2)))
```

Comment: Great, now i got  a nested array.For that i use a Array.flat() to remove one level.
But how would i compare it with the another array and return what is missing with what value.

Ex: 
resultArray = [ ['A',2],['B',3] ]
toCompare = [ ['A:1], ['B',2] ]

this would return B is less than 1 and A is less than 1, or it can even be single value in return 

resultArray = [ ['A',2],['B',3] ]
toCompare = [ ['A:1], ['B',3] ]
for this A is less than 1

Comment: What format do you want that data in? Do you want a literal string saying `\`A is ${num} numbers lower\``? Or another array, like `[[A, 1], [B, 0]]`

Comment: I just  want that it return anything stating that the value is less and more.
For ex. If B in the main array have 2 and the new array have 1, it would return that B requires 1 more value

Answer (score 1):

You could split and then count. I opted to return a plain object (like you mentioned) in a function called `countBySuffix`.

Then I added another function, `diff`, which will compare two such objects (returned by `countBySuffix`) and will return only the differences. A difference is an array with three elements:

```
[suffix, count 1, count 2]
```

Where the suffix in your example would for example be "A", and the counts would be how many times this suffix appeared in the first input, and in the second input.

Snippet:

```js
function countBySuffix(arr) {
  arr = arr.map(s => s.split("-").pop());
  let map = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(s => [s, 0]));
  for (let s of arr) map[s]++;
  return map;
}

function diff(a, b) {
  let res = [];
  for (let prop in a) {
    if (b[prop] != a[prop]) res.push([prop, a[prop], b[prop]]);
  }
  for (let prop in b) {
    if (!a[prop]) res.push([prop, undefined, b[prop]]);
  }
  return res;
}

// demo
let arr1 = [ "5281-A", "5280-A", "5280-B", "5281-B" ];
let arr2 = [ "5284-A", "5283-B", "5282-A"];

let count1 = countBySuffix(arr1);
let count2 = countBySuffix(arr2);

console.log(diff(count1, count2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`

```js
let arr = ["5281-A", "5280-A", "5280-B", "5281-B"]
let map = new Map();
arr.forEach((item) => {
  const txt = item.charAt(item.length - 1);
  if (!map.has(txt)) {
    map.set(txt, 1)
  } else {
    const val = map.get(txt);
    map.set(txt, val + 1)
  }
})
let newArr = [];
for (let [key, value] of map.entries()) {
  newArr.push([key, value])
};
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should create an object:

```
let obj = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
 let letter = item.split("-")[1];
 obj[letter] = obj[letter] ? obj[letter] + 1 : 1;
})

output: {"A": 2, "B": 2}
```

If you need it in ["A", 2] format:

```
let outputArray = Object.entries(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will achive your goal.

```js
let arr = [ "5281-A", "5280-A", "5280-B", "5281-B" ]

let newObj = arr.reduce((a,b) => {
    const str = b.split('-')[1]
    a[str] = a[str] ? a[str] += 1 : 1
    return a
}, {})
```

This answer is better than using for-loops because it can be passed to a new object a lot easier.